# Equation of 27 lines on a cubic surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory

For a smooth cubic surface $S$ in $\mathbf{P}^3$, there're always $27$ lines on it, with the same configuration.

We know the automorphism group of the lines is not solvable.

How do we show the lines cannot be solved by coefficient of the cubic polynomial defining $S$?

Comment: I don't understand what it means for a line to be solved by a coefficient of a polynomial. Can you make your question more precise?

Comment: @Relapsarian It means the line can be expressed as $[SX_0+TX_1\colon SY_0+TY_1\colon SZ_0+TZ_1\colon SW_0+TW_1 ]$ with $X_i,Y_i,Z_i,W_i$ written as $+,-,\times, ^{-1}$ and taking roots of coefficients?